# Convert uppercase letters to lower case and count strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to convert a inputted string to lower case letters. After converting I would like to do a count of all the lower case letters that are from ['a'..'z'].

For example: "This is a TES3T "
result: [(t, 3), (h, 1), (i, 2), (s,2), (a,1) (e,1)]

This is what I have so far:

```
countL :: [Char] -> Char -> Int
countL s c = length ( [x | x <- s, x == c])

letter_count :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]
letter_count s = nub [(c, countL s c) | c <- s]
```

I have found the below to convert a given string into lower case:

```
toLowerString :: [Char] -> [Char]
toLowerString str = [ toLower x | x <- str]
```

But I'm not sure how to use the "toLowerString" with my "letter_count" function and to only read ['a'..'z'].

Am I going completely wrong? Is there an simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try ``toLowerAndFilterString = filter (`elem` ['a'..'z']) . map toLower``.

Comment: fyi, `Data.List.Utils.countElem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some space for optimizations in your solution.

**First** of all, the function `letter_count` runs in O(n^2) time: when the result of `[(c, countL s c) | c <- s]` is computed, for each character of the n letter string a O(n) lookup is performed by `countL`. This is not the optimal time complexity -- counting letters can be done faster.

If you only want to consider letters [a, ..., z], then counting can be done in O(n) time using arrays from `Data.Array` (or, as @dfeuer mentioned in a comment, in O(n log k) time using `Data.IntMap.Strict`. If you want to stick to lists -- which will result with simpler code (which is desired especially for beginners), you can achieve O(n log(n)) complexity by sorting the list first and then counting the letters.

After sorting you are sure that same letters will appear in consecutive blocks, so you can easily group them and count them in linear time.

**Second** optimization is far less important, but it may improve the clarity of your code. Look at your definition of `toLowerString`:

```
toLowerString :: [Char] -> [Char]
toLowerString str = [ toLower x | x <- str]
```

what you do in the fragment `[ toLower x | x <- str]` is exactly what `map` function is made for -- you are replacing each element of some list with a result of some function (here: `toLower`). You can rewrite this part like this:

```
toLowerString :: [Char] -> [Char]
toLowerString str = map toLower str
```

Moreover, now you may observe, that it is possible to omit the `str` argument in the definition -- the code gets even shorter:

```
toLowerString :: [Char] -> [Char]
toLowerString = map toLower
```

---

My solution to your problem would look as follows:

```
import Data.Char (isLetter, toLower)
import Data.List (sort, group)

countLetters str = 
  let 
    filteredStr = filter isLetter str
    lowerCaseStr = map toLower filteredStr
    sortedStr = sort lowerCaseStr
    groupedStr = group sortedStr
  in
  [(h, length fragment) | fragment@(h:_) <- groupedStr]

main = do
  putStrLn "Type the string to count letters in:"
  string <- getLine
  let result = countLetters string
  print result
```

You can try it here:
https://repl.it/repls/GrubbyUnnaturalKitty

If you'd like to make this solution even shorter, you could write it this way:

```
countLetters str = 
  let 
    groupedStr = group . sort . map toLower . filter isLetter $ str
  in
  [(head fragment, length fragment) | fragment <- groupedStr]
```

using function composition operator `.`. The tricky bit may be the usage of `$` operator, which... in fact does nothing -- it applies the function on the left to the parameter given on the right. Its only role is to help to avoid writing too many parentheses -- without it, the line would look like this:

```
    groupedStr = (group . sort . map toLower . filter isLetter) str
```

Please also notice two different ways of extracting the head of the group of letters, while also binding the name `fragment` to the whole group:

**A.** name the whole group as `fragment` and use function `head` in the definition of the resulting tuple:

```
  [(head fragment, length fragment) | fragment <- groupedStr]
```

**B.** name the whole group as fragment, but also name its head as `h` using `@` notation:

```
  [(h, length fragment) | fragment@(h:_) <- groupedStr]
```

Essentially `@` allows you to perform the pattern matching, while also introducing the name for the whole thing before matching takes place.

Comment: The switch from a list comprehension to `map` is not an optimization; the compiled code (and thus the performance) should be identical. But it is clearer.

Comment: you're right, I meant that. Maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Thanks @Radek for the very good explanation. If I decide to use percentage instead of count. Ie. [(t, 0.25), (h, 0.12) ..] as in t = 25% and h = 12%. Could I use similar approach ? I am getting confused when have to combine functions together and your approach seems quite clear

Comment: Yes, you can easily modify my solution to calculate the percentages. Do you want to calculate percentages related to the total number of characters of just the number of letters? e.g. with `aaaa1234` the letter a should get 50% or 100%? If you let me know, I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Short explanation: to get the percentages, basically all you have to do is to calculate the length of `str` or `filteredStr` (depending whether you want non-letter symbols to be taken into account or not -- 50% vs 100% above): `lengthOfStr = length str`
Then modify the last expression as follows:
`[(h, fromIntegral (length fragment) / lengthOfStr) | fragment@(h:_) <- groupedStr]`

Comment: Thanks @radek yes, so basically I want to only read letters ignoring any other characters or numbers and have the percentage of it, if possible in two decimals only ie. "(t, 0.12)"  = 12%. I have tried using floating before and had trouble making it to display in two decimals float instead of 0.12213123. If you extend your answer I'll mark as accepted answer!

Comment: @VictorAngelo Here's your modified version with percentages:
https://repl.it/repls/StridentYummyFinnishspitz

Answer (score 3):

A nice and short solution to count the letters would be to use the function `group` from the module `Data.List` ([link](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group)). It takes a list and returns a list of its grouped elements. To get unique groups, simply sort your input string first. E.g.:

```
group (sort "Hello World")
```

will give you:

```
[" ","H","W","d","e","lll","oo","r"]
```

All you need to do is to convert each of those substrings, into a tuple of its length and its first letter:

```
map (\s -> (head s, length s))
```

So your `letter_count` will be:

```
letter_count :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]
letter_count = map (\s -> (head s, length s)) . group . sort
```

Answer (score 1):

The array solution Radek mentioned looks like this:

```
import qualified Data.Array.Unboxed as A
import Data.Char ( isAsciiLower )

countLettersArr :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]
countLettersArr cs = filter ((/= 0) . snd) (A.assocs arr)
  where
    arr :: A.UArray Char Int
    arr = A.accumArray (+) 0 ('a', 'z')
          [(c, 1 :: Int) | c <- cs, isAsciiLower c]
```

`countLettersArr` will simply drop any characters that are not lower-case letters. This can be generalized somewhat. Enabling `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`,

```
countIxesArr :: forall c. A.Ix c => (c,c) -> [c] -> [(c, Int)]
countIxesArr (lo,hi) cs = filter ((/= 0) . snd) (A.assocs arr)
  where
    arr :: A.UArray c Int
    arr = A.accumArray (+) 0 (lo, hi)
          [(c, 1::Int) | c <- cs, A.inRange (lo,hi) c]
```

A somewhat less efficient approach is to use an `IntMap` instead of an array. This is slightly painful because `IntMap` only accepts `Int` indices, but it works in pretty much the same way: `fromListWith` is very similar to `accumArray`. This version will record *whatever* characters you throw at it, lower-case letters or not. You could easily change this by adding a guard to the list comprehension in the definition of `im`.

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import Data.Char (ord, chr)
import Data.Bifunctor (first)

-- Count how many of each letter appear in a string.
countLettersIM :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]
countLettersIM cs = map (first chr) . M.toList $ im
  where
    im :: M.IntMap Int
    im = M.fromListWith (+) [(ord c, 1) | c <- cs]
```

If you like, you can generalize this as well, in a slightly different direction:

```
countEnumsIM :: Enum a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
countEnumsIM cs = map (first toEnum) . M.toList $ im
  where
    im = M.fromListWith (+) [(fromEnum c,1) | c <- cs]
```